# Question mark(?) getting replaced by %3F in jax-rs jersey

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jersey, jax-rs

While calling an API in jax-rs jersey I have to pass a parameter. But that is getting converted into some special character.
I have declared a variable `mCopy` which will take either false or true based on some conditions.
My URI is

```
URI:- https://idcs-oda-xxxxxxx.com/api/v1/bots/pushRequests?copy=true
```

My code is

```
Response rawres = client.target("https://idcs-oda-xxxxxxx.com")
                                .path("bots")
                                .path("pushRequests?copy="+mcopy")
                                .request().header("Authorization",access_token)
                                .post(null, Response.class);
```

it throws error

```
  https://idcs-oda-xxxxxxx.com/api/v1/bots/pushRequests%3Fcopy=false, status=404, reason=Not Found
```

actually `pushRequests?copy=mCopy` getting converted to `pushRequests%3Fcopy=false`

how can I keep ? symbol as it is?

Comment: `copy=true` looks like it's the query part or the URL, not part of the path.

Comment: @Gereon  ya Gereon, now I understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using the API correctly.  You want to do:

```
Response rawres = client.target("https://idcs-oda-xxxxxxx.com")
                                .path("bots")
                                .path("pushRequests")
                                .queryParam("copy", mcopy) // this is the change
                                .request().header("Authorization",access_token)
                                .post(null, Response.class);
```